# Does the "average" of an integral converges to a point value of the integrand when the domain of integration shrinks to the point?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $B_n$ be the closed ball at origin with radius $1/n$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Think of the normal Gaussian measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}^m$ and consider
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\mu(B_n) \sup_{x \in B_n}\lVert x \rVert^2} \int_{B_n} \lVert x \rVert^2 d\mu(x).
\end{equation}

Then, I strongly suspect that this quantity converges to $1$ as $n \to \infty$. However, I cannot justify my guess rigorously..

Could anyone please explain how it works?

Comment: I'd like a crack at this but I'm trying to figure what this looks like in one dimension - especially a Borel probability measure.

Comment: If any inner regular Borel measure is too arbitrary, you can just specialize to Gaussian measures, like the normal one.

Comment: I may be mistaken, but it seems that the Dominated Convergence theorem would suggest this tends to 0 in one dimension

Comment: Dominated convergence? The supremum will prevent that, I believe..

Comment: I narrowed down to the Gaussian case only..

Comment: It doesn't converge to $1$. It seems to converge to $1/3$ for $m=1$

Comment: Ok I computed that as well. Now I am trying to figure out dependence on the dimension $m$. I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the best measure theory experience, but for the Gaussian, the limit is a constant. In that case, we have

$$ d\mu = e^{-x^2/2} \ dx $$

and we should also remark that $\| x \|^2 \leq \frac{1}{n^2}$ when $x \in B_n.$ So we write

$$\frac{1}{\mu(B_n) \| x \|_\infty ^2} \int_{-1/n} ^{1/n} x^2 e^{-x^2/2} \ dx \leq \frac{n^3}{2} \int_{-1/n} ^{1/n} x^2 \ dx = \frac{n^3}{2} \cdot \frac{2}{3n^3} = \frac{1}{3}$$

and the sequence of integrals on the left is convergent by DCT.

(I'll remark that this isn't a full solution but rather an attempt with some elementary estimates.)

Comment: By a constant, you mean nonzero?

Comment: Need to examine dependence on the dimension...

Comment: And you get $1/3$ for the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: I'm thinking of how to generalize this argument. Might be a while, but I don't expect success.